# Local development on containerized microfrontends

Tags: reactjs, typescript, docker, docker-compose, micro-frontend

I'm currently working on a React and Typescript project that has multiple microfrontends imported as NPM packages and (the root project) is built/ran through Dockerfile/docker-compose. It works fine in production, as each microfrontend is built and published to a registry and imported through NPM.

Given that, I was trying to setup up a way to ease local development and allow changes in one microfrontend to automatically reflect on the root project currently running.

So far, i have tried:

- Creating a docker bind-mount from the microfrontend's source to its corresponding folder inside node_modules. It didn't work because the root project expects plain JS code (already transpiled from Typescript) inside the node_modules
- Copying the microfrontend's source during the build step and compiling through Typescript alongside the root project. Didn't work because since they are diferent repositories, they are stored in different directories and, therefore, ouside eachother's build context.
- Creating a docker named volume, building the microfrontend, copying it's dist into the volume and mounting it to the corresponding folder inside the root project's node_modules. This one worked but doesn't apply changes from the root project, forcing me to repeat all steps every time and making it quite slow (due to the many manual operations it takes)